# In Kotlin when `when` is better solution than `if`?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here I have a sample
I am wondering when `when` is better solution than `if` ?

```
  when {
        uri.isNullOrEmpty() -> Log.i()
        else -> display(uri)
    }

    if(uri.isNullOrEmpty()){
       Log.i()
    }else{
       display(uri)
    }
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with performance it is just a replacement for if expression for more readiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer @Juan Ortiz Couder gave, it depends to your case that which one is better. Maybe when is better when you have several cases. If is better when you have just 1 condition or two cases that you can use if else for it. For example you use `if(text.isEmpty()){...
}
else{...
}`

Here if has better readability than when.

Both of them are useful and we can't say one is better than another. It depends.

Answer (score 1):

When is used more similar as a switch statement. It is used instead of having to write several else if statements.

```
when (x) {
    3 -> print("x == 3")
    8 -> print("x == 8")
else -> { 
    print("x is neither 3 nor 8")
}
```

This is very helpful instead of having to write

```
if (x == 3) {
    print("x == 3")
} else if (x == 8){
    print("x == 8")
} else {
    print("x is neither 3 nor 8")
}
```

Comment: I know this but when is more optimal than if ,yes? if we consider that maybe when is better solution than if ,yes or not ?

Comment: In terms of performance, there shouldn't be any difference between when and if. It depends on which you like best.